# What happens internally when i do driver.findElementById("some id").click()? does it execute a javascript?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

What happens internally when i do `driver.findElementById("some id").click()`? does it execute a javascript? i would like to understand how the click works? does it execute a java script or does it do some API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're specifically asking, "What happens when I do `WebElement.click()`?" the answer is, "It depends." Most browser drivers use one of two different modes when `click()` is called. If you are using so-called "native events," then the click is performed using OS-level mechanisms appropriate for the platform you're running on. On the other hand, if you're using "simulated events," those are JavaScript-simulated clicks on the element. You can also tell most drivers, usually through a `DesiredCapability`, that you want to use native or synthetic events. Whether you're actually using native or synthetic events in your specific case is highly dependent on browser and platform, as the defaults differ from browser to browser and OS to OS.

If your question is more generic, for instance, "Does WebDriver use JavaScript for any of its functionality?" the answer is almost certainly, "Yes, drivers do rely on JavaScript for at least some functionality." Note that this means turning off JavaScript execution via your browser's settings will almost certainly break the driver for whatever browser you're trying to automate.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of selenium, Selenium RC, use to inject the javascript functions when the browser loads the page, and was targeting all the browsers with this approach.

With the introduction of the Selenium WebDriver, the selenium uses browsers built-in support for automation, which varies depending on the browser. So a Firefox Plugin for Firefox, a .dll for IE, Chromium maintains a ChromeDriver for Chrome automation. So a native support vs. the old javascript approach.

The introductory to a Web driver will move you closer if you haven't covered it already
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like web driver uses simulated events pls refer to - https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#clicking

Comment: links only answers are not welcomed here as the link may be get broken in the future which will make your answer useless, kindly include some snippets from your link in your answer.